# How to purge all transient caches?

Tags: cache, transient

Is there an easy way to delete all transient caches? A plugin maybe? Or like in drupal "drush cc all"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install https://wp-cli.org/ and use the command

```
wp transient delete --all
```

Answer (score 3):

Not tested, but if you need a quick and dirty way, you could put a script like this in your WordPress folder and call it each time:

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require('wp-blog-header.php');

global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query( "DELETE FROM $wpdb->options WHERE option_name LIKE '%\_transient\_%'" );
```

Not to be used on a production server.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access your database through phpmyadmin or something equivalent, I would recommand you to use this :

```
DELETE a, b FROM wp_options a, wp_options b  WHERE a.option_name LIKE '_transient_%' 
AND a.option_name 
NOT LIKE '_transient_timeout_%' 
AND b.option_name = CONCAT( '_transient_timeout_', SUBSTRING( a.option_name, CHAR_LENGTH('_transient_') + 1 ) ) AND b.option_value < UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

Comment: What is the meaning of your SQL delete command @JMau?

Comment: @NamGVU it's a little bit complicated but basically we do not want to mess up with transients used by WP core itself and those which are actually running. We want only expired transients.