# Can we turn off Wordpress `transient` cache?

Tags: cache, transient

When studying Wordpress, I notice that a lot of database changes are on `wp_options` table - a closer monitor will show that a lot of `transient` related changes are made.

I wonder if we can turn off Wordpress's Ttransient cache?

p.s.

A way to delete all transient cache is discussed [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/102071/992) - after removed, cache will be recreated as [@Pieter Goosen](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/31545/pieter-goosen) shared below.

Comment: Why @PieterGoosen?

Comment: Transients are used to store the results from big time consuming actions. Without them, your site will most probably just crash due to timing out

Comment: So... is it okie if I remove those `transient` rows in `wp_options` table? Will those removed be re-created again - for another big time comsuming?

Comment: I'm thinking about moving a Wordpress web application around different hosts - and `transient cache` seems to cause problems to me.

Comment: You can delete them, they will be recreated. Transients get deleted and recreated all the time, this is normal.

Comment: @PieterGoosen, This isn't actually a duplicate. I know a way to completely disable the transient cache. and some very strong cautionary statements (reasons why to not do it). Can you reopen and ping me when you do?